# Sencha Touch and PHP Webservice

Tags: php, json, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm currently learning sencha touch and as a test i wrote a little webservice and i want to display the resulting items in a list

But i can't get it to work...

```js
Ext.define('GS.view.ListTest', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',

    requires:[
        'Ext.dataview.List',
        'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP',
        'Ext.data.Store'
    ],
    xtype:'listpanel',
    config: {
        title: 'Fifa List',
        iconCls: 'star',

        items: {
            xtype: 'list',
            itemTpl: '{Player1}',

            store: {
                autoLoad: true,
                fields: ['MatchID','Player1', 'ScorePlayer1' ,'ScorePlayer2','Player2'],

                proxy: {
                    type: 'jsonp',
                    url: 'http://fifa.verhulstrobin.be/webservices/getMatches.php',
                    reader: {
                        type:'json',
                        rootProperty: 'matches'
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
});
```

I check and my json is valid ...
All it says in the console is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: Any particular reaxon you are using a JSONP proxy ? Couldn't you just use an Ajax Proxy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
items: {
    xtype: 'list',
    itemTpl: '{match.Player1}',

    store:new  Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        autoLoad: true,
        fields: ['match'],

        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: 'http://fifa.verhulstrobin.be/webservices/getMatches.php',
            reader: {
                type:'json',
                rootProperty: 'matches'
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209398/sencha-touch-2-store-typeerror/11209631#11209631 referr this answer

Comment: this is a discouraged approach

Comment: personaly I never sugest this way.I strongly recomended use MVC structure.but your code already done and just one error is there that's why I try to solve it.

Comment: What does MVC structure have to do with you using new Ext.create ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead :

```
    items: {
        xtype: 'list',
        itemTpl: '{match.Player1}',

        store: {
            autoLoad: true,
            fields: ['match'],

            proxy: {
                type: 'jsonp',
                url: 'http://fifa.verhulstrobin.be/webservices/getMatches.php',
                reader: {
                    type:'json',
                    rootProperty: 'matches'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your webservice response I notice that it does not wrap the JSON answer in a function call like JSONP would require. You need to return an item like this:

```
Ext.data.JsonP.callback1({});
```

Where the argument of the function must be your actual JSON data instead of an empty object,  and the name of the function "Ext.data.JsonP.callback1" is passed to your webservice as parameter named "callback" by the Ext Store.

You can however customize that parameter's name with callbackKey on the proxy:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'User',
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url : 'http://domainB.com/users',
        callbackKey: 'theCallbackFunction'  // <--
    }
});
```

For more detailed information on JSONP and how to implement it for an Ext Js Store you could refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP
and http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP